# Issue with Fabs() and Abs()

Tags: c, if-statement, variables

My program checks to see if the max price is bigger than the price you spent. If the max price is bigger than the price you spent it turns the absolute value of two floats; but when I use fabs(), returns "Wow, you overspent on that first cupcake...you owe $0.00. Bye!".
I also tried abs(), but that didn't work.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    float maxPrice;
    char flavor[20];
    char flavor2[20];
    float price;
    double price2;
    char anotherCupcake[20];
    double newPrice;
    newPrice=maxPrice-price;

   // int idxToDel = 2;
    //memove(&word[idxToDel], &word[idxToDel + 1], strlen(word) - idxToDel);

    printf("Please enter starting budget: ");
    scanf("%f", &maxPrice);
    printf("Enter the flavor of cupcake 1: ");
    scanf("%s", &flavor);
    printf("Enter the price of %s cupcake: $", flavor);
    scanf("%f", &price);

    //determining if you have enough money for a second cupcake
    if(price == maxPrice)
    {
        printf("\nOops! No more money left to spend on anymore cupcakes...enjoy the %s one! Bye!", flavor);
    }
    else if(price > maxPrice)
    {

        printf("\nWow, you overspent on that first cupcake...you owe $%.2lf. Bye!", fabs(newPrice)*1.0);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Ok, looks like you you have $.2lf left to spend on cupcakes...  Would you like to get another one?", maxPrice - price);
        scanf("%s", &anotherCupcake);
        if(anotherCupcake == "yes")
        {
           printf("Enter the flavor of cupcake 2: ");
           scanf("%s", &flavor2);
           printf("Enter the price of cupcake 2 $: ");
           scanf("%f", &price2);
           printf("Done! Enjoy your %s and %s cupcakes! Bye!", flavor, flavor2);

        }
        else
        {
            printf("Ok then...Enjoy that one %s cupcake! Bye!", flavor);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to put the `newPrice=maxPrice-price;` calculation ***after*** you have assigned values to `maxPrice` and `price`.

Comment: Sigh. Turn on warnings in your compiler, elevate them to errors, and pay attention to them. With Clang, start with `-Wmost -Werror`. With GCC, start with `-Wall -Werror`. With MSVC, start with `/W3 /Wx`. Fix the errors the compiler reports. For character arrays, pass the address of the first element to `scanf`, not the address of the array. Use `%lf` to scan a `double`, not `%f`. Initialize `price` before you use it. Do not use `maxPrice` before it is set by `scanf`; move that to after the `scanf`. Change `$.2f` to `%.2lf`. You cannot compare strings with `==`; use `strcmp`.

Comment: In the future, when entering questions about a program that is not working, provide a [mre]. That includes not just source code but an exact copy of input that reproduces the problem, an exact copy of output observed, and a copy or good description of the output desired instead.

Comment: @Eric: `-Wall -Wextra` is about the bare minimum on GCC, because `-Wall` is not "all", by a long shot. I would guess the situation being similar with Clang.

Comment: @zackBYE344 Enable all warnings - it saves you time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to calculate `newPrice` with current values of
`maxPrice-price`, not at the beginning when neither `maxPrice` nor
`price` are initialized. Like that:

```
      newPrice = maxPrice - price;
      printf("\nWow, you overspent on that first cupcake...you owe $%.2lf. Bye!\n", fabs(newPrice)*1.0);
```

It'll work like that:

```
$ ./main
Please enter starting budget: 10
Enter the flavor of cupcake 1: 1
Enter the price of 1 cupcake: $18

Wow, you overspent on that first cupcake...you owe $8.00. Bye!
```

As a sidenote, you didn't specify what compiler you're using but the minimum set of flags you should use with gcc/clang is `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` and fix all warnings.

Comment: On StackOverflow you thank by upvoting and/or accepting answer. See
[what should I do when someone answers my
question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).